# Where can I learn to make Force Wielder hilts?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I have Artificing, which allows me to make various lightsaber components.

Right now, I can make Resolve Hilt 2-7 and Might Hilt 2-7, but during questing, I received a Force Wielder Hilt 6 as a quest reward.

Where can I learn how to make those myself?

Comment: Just an FYI, Resolve Hilts and Force Wielder hilts up the same stats, but in opposite proportions.  Blue Force Wielder Hilt 6 is +10 Endurance +7 Willpower, Blue Resolve Hilt 6 is +7 Endurance +10 Willpower.

Comment: **You cannot**. (this answer is too short to even be allowed as a comment...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make every item in the game. Many are world drops, quest rewards, or must be purchased at vendors. Only some of them are craftable.

The specific items you mention are not available for crafting.

See the crafting lists at any of the item database sites like [DarthHaterDB](http://db.darthhater.com/recipes/artifice/).

Answer (score 1):

You can start crafting those hilts starting with [Force Wielder 10](http://www.torhead.com/item/8j78irm/advanced-force-wielder-hilt-10).  You learn this from the artifice trainer.

As Mufasa notes you just can't learn to craft some items, such as the Force Wielder 6 hilt you received.  There are schematics you can get for some of them however, at least since update 1.2, such as the [Green Sharp Crystal](http://www.torhead.com/schematic/9o9Mg1k/green-sharp-crystal) which cannot be learned from the trainer.